# Is there a ManagedExecutorService queue limit?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara, microprofile

I'm using the [ManagedExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) to process a list of jobs. I process the jobs in the main thread and execute each job with the ManagedExecutor. It's possible in the future that the job size exceeds the pool size...so I wonder, is there a queue or is an exception raised when this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the number of jobs exceeds the pool size then items are added to a queue. When the queue is full, then an exception is thrown.

The details of a managed executor service can be found in the admin console under Resources -> Concurrent Resources -> Managed Executor Services -> (name of executor service)

The pool size and queue size for the default managed executor service (which has a JNDI name of
concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService) are both `Integer.MAX_SIZE` which is 2147483647.